# How to remove accounts from "Choose an account" list in Google sign in?

Tags: google-account, login, google-multi-login

When signing in with Google (OAuth), it shows a list of accounts it already knows about. How can I remove *some* accounts from this list?

[image: sign in with google]

I know I can nuke all of them by deleting all cookies, but I'd prefer to remove one account that I don't want there, rather than all of them.

There used to be an ability to edit this list in the older version of this screen, but in 2018 redesign Google has removed `[×]` buttons next to the accounts.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

- log out
- open **https://accounts.google.com/**
- click on **Continue**
- select **Remove an account**
- click on that **⊖**
- select **Yes, remove***
- done

[image: 0]

- old GUI: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0vEr.gif**

Comment: Thank you. Excellent answer!

Comment: This is now out of date. See the other answer.

Comment: @Shwaydogg untrue. its still valid and up to date

Comment: @user0 If you are still logged into another account the link you provided does not take you to the screen in your gif. And when I've seen that ux it does not have the "Remove and Account" as you show.  The other answer seems to be the more reliable one now at the least...

Answer (score 35):

Looks like it's changed again.

You have to first click the button "Sign Out of All Accounts".

If you get the list of accounts, just click on the red icons to remove the account from the list.

[image]

If not just follow these steps

1. Go to Google.com
2. Click sign in if you're not already signed in.
3. Click your profile image.
4. Look for the account you want to remove make sure it doesn't say "session expired". If it does you need to click "Sign Out of All Accounts" and go back to step 1.
5. If it says session expired now that you've signed back in you should see a remove button as seen in the gif below.

[image: How to remove an account from the Google account list in a browser]

Comment: it worked fine!

Comment: Thanks, but ick. If I want to remove one account, I need to sign out of ALL of my accounts? Why.

Comment: This works as of 6/17/21

Comment: I have to sign out of all of my accounts just to remove an old account wtf? This worked, tho, thank you!

Comment: This is a terrible answer except that it's correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 26):

I wasn't getting the remove button in the account chooser either, but it's actually easier now:

1. Sign out of the account you want to remove.
2. Click on the accounts drop down menu (top right).
3. Click the signed out account.
4. You'll see overlaid options to Remove or Sign In; click Remove.

[image: Account Menu]

Comment: this isn't showing up for me.  do you know the answer for safari?

Comment: This is not browser-dependent; you're probably mixing this up with the Chrome account badge, which is in Chrome's top-right corner; this refers to the Google account badge, which is in the top-right corner of most Google-owned sites.

Comment: There is no profile image in the top right once I've logged out.  This is true on google.com, accounts.google.com, and gmail.com.

Comment: How does one accomplish step one?

Comment: No longer works, see below answer