# How do I remove someone else's Google account from my device?

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-account-profile

My friend logged onto her Google account on my device. Now I can't access my own Google account. I've pressed sign out, removed the account with the "remove account" button, and signed back in, but every time I try to sign back into my account my friend's account will pop up and ask if I recognize this account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove accounts from "Choose an account" list in Google sign in?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/123604/how-to-remove-accounts-from-choose-an-account-list-in-google-sign-in)

Answer (score 1):

- log out
- open **https://accounts.google.com/**
- select **Remove account**
- click on that **X**
- select **Yes, remove**
- done

[image: x]

Comment: This no longer works. I think the closest thing you can do is sign out of the account from a different device. Otherwise, you'll need to use `Sign Out of All Accounts`