# How to remove accounts from “Choose an account” list in Google WITHOUT signing in?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I was helping my mother troubleshoot a problem with her Gmail and now every time I go to use Gmail, her account comes up as the default one. I don't know her password, but I can't sign out of her account without signing in first, so I can't remove it from the list.

This is really annoying.

Is there any way I can remove this entry **without** having to log in to her account?

All other solutions I have seen to this issue involve somehow signing out of the account before being able to remove it. I cannot do that because when I go to click on the account to switch to it, I am asked to verify that it's me (which it isn't) and type a password (which I don't know.)

[image: Infographic]

Comment: Duplicate of [How to remove accounts from "Choose an account" list in Google sign in?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/123604/how-to-remove-accounts-from-choose-an-account-list-in-google-sign-in)

Comment: NOT a duplicate. That solution specifically states you need to log out of the account. I can't log out of the account because I can't log in to it.

Comment: if you (mother's acc) are not logged in you (mother's acc) don't need to log out eg you (mother's acc) are logged out (just make sure that you are logged out from your account to perform removal from login list). in other words: log out of all accounts you are able to log out or simply press ctrl+shift+delete and delete all cookies which will forcefully log you out of all acounts

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean. It's totally counter-intuitive, but signing out of MY account allows me to remove HER account from the list. I didn't expect that at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit "Sign out" in that drop-down menu, and you'll be signed out of all the accounts. You need to sign out of all the accounts, seeing as her account is the default account.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, not intuitive, that to sign out of default account you need to sign out of any other account. But it works.