# How to sign out/remove a gmail account from chrome?

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-chrome

I am signed in to 5 accounts in chrome, I want to remove two of them, one having a session that expired and that I can no longer sign in to, because it's not mine.

All I see is a button that says sign out of all accounts, I don't want that. I used to be able to just remove the account I do not need from the top right side, I can't find that any more.

When you click on the avatar, there's a dropdown, there used to be a button, which lets you manage your accounts with an S, which in terms used to let you remove the account you no longer need. I can't find it!

Clicking "sign out of all" is not an option.

In case there's anything not clear

[image]

Do you see that dropdown? That user has 3 accounts which he's signed into, how to sign out of 2 of them and keep only one? How to remove 2 out of 3? I want to get to this screen, like [this](https://www.bestoninternet.com/compute/browser/how-to-remove-google-account-from-chrome/)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove accounts from "Choose an account" list in Google sign in?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/123604/how-to-remove-accounts-from-choose-an-account-list-in-google-sign-in)

Answer (score 1):

Using another device e.g. laptop, open Chrome click on your account icon at top right of screen, go to 'Manage your Google Account'.
Select the 'Security' tab. Scroll down to 'Your Devices'. Go down to 'Manage Devices' and sign out of the ones you want to sign out of there.
Hope this helps,
David